# Cassandra event storage

Tags: cassandra

Is there a best way to store data in a Cassandra database if I will want to search the data in these 2 ways:

1) The last 20 "error" event_types for user_id "123"
2) All "login" event_types in the past day

Would this work:
`CREATE TABLE events (
  user_id text,
  event_type text,
  data text,
  timestamp timestamp,
  PRIMARY KEY  (event_type, timestamp, userid) );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create two tables for this (at least in version 2.x).

From version 3.5 onward you can use [SASI](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/refCreateSASIIndex.html).

> 1) The last 20 "error" event_types for user_id "123"

`CREATE TABLE events (
  user_id text,
  event_type text,
  data text,
  timestamp timestamp DESC,
  PRIMARY KEY  ((userid,event_type), timestamp) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);`

Now you can get the data by the following query.

`select * from events where user_id = '123' and event_type = 'error' limit 20`

> 2) All "login" event_types in the past day

`CREATE TABLE events_by_type (
  user_id text,
  event_type text,
  data text,
  timestamp timestamp DESC,
  PRIMARY KEY  (event_type, timestamp) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp DESC);`

Now you can get the data by the following query.

`select * from events where event_type = 'login' and timestamp > ddmmyyyy`